# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')?

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why i keep getting this error. Please help.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') at script.js:35:21

```
const testCase = ["A", "A", "C", "D"];
const shelf1 = [
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["E", "F", "G", "H"],
  ["I", "J", "A", "B"],
  ["C", "D", "E", "F"],
  ["G", "H", "I", "J"],
  ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
  ["E", "F", "G", "H"],
  ["I", "J", "A", "B"],
  ["C", "D", "E", "F"],
  ["G", "H", "I", "J"],
];
const shelf2 = [
  ["A", "A", "A"],
  ["B", "B", "B"],
  ["C", "C", "C"],
  ["D", "D", "D"],
  ["E", "E", "E"],
  ["F", "F", "F"],
  ["G", "G", "G"],
  ["H", "H", "H"],
  ["I", "I", "I"],
  ["J", "J", "J"],
];
const test = testCase.slice();
console.log(test);
let curShelf = [];
curShelf = shelf1; // shelf1, shelf2
console.log(curShelf);
let i = 0;

for (let j = 0; test !== []; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < testCase.length; i++) {
    if (curShelf[j].includes(testCase[i])) {
      let index1 = test.indexOf(testCase[i]);
      let index2 = curShelf[j].indexOf(testCase[i]);
      if (index1 > -1 && index2 > -1) {
        test.splice(index1, 1);
        curShelf[j].splice(index2, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  j++; 
  console.log(test, j);
}

const distance = count + j;
console.log("cock");
console.log("Total distance: ", distance);
```

It won't appear when i tried remove `j++` but i'm just clueless.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: `test != []` is always true, so your loop keeps going past the end of the `curShelf` array.

Comment: Use `test.length > 0` to tell if `test` is not empty.

Comment: no explanation on what you are trying to achieve. Please update question

Comment: Why is `j++` twice? If this is intended then use `j += 2` in the `for()` statement and get rid of the other one. This is just a minor remark, not the cause of your error. The error happens because the code accesses `curShelf[j]` and expects it to be an array but there is no validation of `j` against the length of `curShelf` and this leads to a situation when `j` is beyond the last index of `curShelf` and consequently `curShelf[j]` is evaluated to `undefined`. That does not have the properties `.includes()` or `.indexOf()` or `.splice()`. Always check the array indices against the array size.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `test != []` because arrays are by reference & your condition is always `true` as it's comparing for a new reference every-time. Instead use a condition like `test.length > 0`  where you have to iterate until the end of array.